# Python-3.8.3 not installing in Oracle Linux Server 7.3?

Tags: linux, python-3.8, oraclelinux

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.3/Python-3.8.3.tgz

Have  unzipped Python-3.8.3.tgz and after unzip ,folder not has bin folder

Have copied unzipped Python3.8.3 from working Oracle Linux Server 7.6 server and ran python3 or python8.3 but saying command not found

[image: Error Screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where you put the unzipped python directory,
but unless you added that directory is in your path you will need to run it like this from current directory

```
./python3
# or
./python3.8
```

Or add the unzipped directory to path.

```
# for current session only
export PATH=$PATH:/your/unzipped/python/dir
# to add permanently
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/your/unzipped/python/dir' >> ~/.bashrc
# or ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: i am directly running inside bin folder

Comment: But this is the python bin, is this dir in your path?

Comment: Also why not use `yum install -y python3`?

Comment: Thanks adding bin to path worked!!. without adding to PATH if we navigate bin directory it was not working..bash never searches for command in the current directory ever ?

Comment: Right but you can add `./` this means run from current directory even if the app is not in path.